# Matching the exact string

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, aws

I am extracting some data from my AWS account using AWS cli. I am not able to extract the exact string. When I am giving the following command: -

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`Operating System`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value] [0][0], InstanceId, InstanceType,VpcId, State.Name, PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress]
'| column -t | grep production
```

I am getting the output as

```
 sftp_gateway_instance        rhel     production  i-0aec9xxxxxxxxxxxd  t2.xlarge   vpc-zzzzzz1b  running  2.3.4.5    3.2.1.2
 abc-production-nav-1         rhel     production  i-0e4xxxxxxxxxxxxx3  t2.xlarge   vpc-zzzzzz1b  running  1.1.6.5    None
 xyz-produ-nav                rhel     production  i-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxx18  t2.xlarge   vpc-zzzzzz1b  running  2.8.0.4    None
 solutions-production-navi    centos   uat         i-08fffffffffff86c8  t2.large    vpc-zzzzzz1b  running  2.8.9.2    None
```

In the output provided above I don't want the last row because the production is mentioned in the name of instance not in the environment column.

I tried below awk command but in that case the output in not coming in proper column format

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`Operating System`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value] [0][0], InstanceId, InstanceType,VpcId, State.Name, PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress]
'| awk -F ' ' '$3 == "production" {print $1 "\t\t" $2 "\t" $3"\t" $4"\t" $5"\t" $6"\t" $7"\t" $8"\t" $9 }'
```

The output in this case is like below:-

```
abc-production  centos  production  i-xyzabcdef t2.xlarge   vpc-xyzabc  running 2.18.1.0    None
doc-pdf-prod windows production i-xyzabcdef t2.large    vpc-xyzabc  running 172.18.70.229   None
```

I want the output in proper column format like the above output which i am getting using grep. Could anyone please suggest what can be done for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `grep production`, which matches any line with "production" within it, use `awk '$3 == "production"'`, which only matches lines in which the third field is "production".

No need for anything further within the `awk` : by default it will then print the entire matching line.